# Creating an android smart app banner

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, android-widget, ios6

Is there any solution for Android devices similar to the iOS 6 smart app banner?

**Here is the code for smart app banner**

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=311507490, affiliate-data=partnerId=30&siteID=k1CkFsOh4nQ"/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You are unclear on what or how you want to ban apps, when and where.  FYI "blocker" apps don't really work.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: thanks for your reply...i used this and achieved for ios6 http://www.macgasm.net/2012/09/19/ios-6-smart-app-banners/ is there a way to implement for android devices

Comment: Duplicate of this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074694/smart-app-banners-windows-store-app-html-meta-tag-equivalent-for-android-google/13075180#13075180 (answer: no, not really)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357191/does-meta-name-google-play-app-work/23580770#23580770

Comment: You should check out the Branch cross platform app banner. It also does click/download tracking and is free to use: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> Since Chrome 44 Beta you can push your app in Chrome for Android with
> a native app install banner on your website.

[Please see the answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner#32046978)

---

### Old answer

I needed that myself, so I created a jquery plugin to mimic a smart banner for Android and older iOS versions.

https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner

Comment: Does your plugin support the app-argument=myURL property, like in iOS smart banners, that allows you to pass a URL to the app ?

Comment: Not yet. I was already planning to implement that next week, so hold tight.

Comment: do you implemented checking app installed or not for android ? i m using your js but in case of android everytime it shows "view" not "open" even if app is installed in phone.

Comment: I can't seem to get the banner to display (whether viewing site on desktop or on actual android device.) Even the demo page that comes with the plugin doesn't appear to display anything. Is the code current?

Comment: @EmmyS Make sure that you're using version 1.0.0 https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels - I am. Does it require jquery 1.8 as shown in the sample? We're using an older version and can't update for various reasons. But again, even using the sample code provided, and keeping the hosted 1.8 version, it still isn't showing anything other than the `...` text in the body before the script stuff starts.

Comment: @EmmyS Ask a new question on stackoverflow for this and make sure to include a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please may i know how to get url from smart app banner in android?i am wasting time around 2 days and i have done as deep link concept in android default behavior.its working fine but when i try to smart app banner,i confused.please guide me

Comment: @patrioit Ask a new question on stackoverflow for this and make sure to include a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Arnold Daniels i have asked as new question regarding smart app banner in android.please just respond me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735762/getting-url-from-smart-app-banner-in-android

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels: Your plugin doesn't seem to work position-fixed menus, or have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Jasny - sorry to rez this thread but can you complete my pull request containing cleanups of the jquery smartbanner repo

Comment: Actually scratch that, @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels there are about 27 pull requests held in limbo. Help make the repo better plz, don't let it die!

Comment: @SMT It has become hack on hack. If I accept one PR, 2 others are no longer mergable. I really need some collaborators on this project so we can create a v2.

Comment: @Arnold Daniels Is there a feature to display rating from Google Play / App Store? I had try your code. But I don't find it

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer valid. I think it's now https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner

Answer (score 30):

Since Chrome 44 Beta you can push your app in Chrome for Android with a native app install banner on your website. There are a couple of criteria that need to be met in order to enable it:

- You will need a [web app manifest file](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android)
- You will have to serve your web using https
- The user has visited your site twice over two separate days during the course of two weeks.

Read more about it in the [official docs from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native).

Comment: This is not true. It only enables your website to act like native app by letting the user to pin/add shortcut/bookmark on the homescreen for quick access. It doesn't really take you to the app store for you download the native app. The approach that you're describing is when one wants to make a website act like native. That's completely different than what OP is asking.

Comment: Please read the "Native app install banner" part of the posted link. This is exactly what the OP is asking about.

Comment: No. Please read the article. Since Chrome 44 you can add Native app install banners pointing to Google Play. I would suggest you reading my answer AND the official Google post I have linked to. Search for "Native app install banner " on that page. You can read right?

Comment: "A new powerful feature for native app developers also landed in Chrome 44 Beta. Native App install banners are similar to Web app install banners, but instead of adding to the Home Screen will let the user inline install your native app."

Comment: but, does this 'Native App Install' banner pass the context/data from my web page (where i clicked this banner) to my App that will be launched post installation from store ?

Comment: It seems the links are broken and send users to a different site now. I think I found it in the internet archive though: https://web.archive.org/web/20160428180729/https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android?hl=en

Comment: @dkniffin - seems to work now, at least for me - redirects to web.dev

Answer (score 2):

You add the Google Sign-In button to your page with a special parameter and then users can sign in and specify which device to install your app to directly from your website.

This is the most "officially supported" implementation I know of:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/android-app-installs

From the link:

By adding the Google Sign-In button to your web site, you can automatically prompt your users to download your Android app over the air to their Android devices. To enable this feature, you must use the same Google Developers Console project for your Web and Android clients, and configure your web app's sign-in button.

Your web app must use the Google Sign-In button to prompt your web site users to download your app the first time that they sign in. This feature is enabled by adding the apppackagename parameter to your sign-in button.

Answer (score 1):

There are two APIs available:

- To detect if the **app is already installed** use getInstalledRelatedApps (only for Chrome 80+)

  - Article with general information: https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/
  - Docs and demo (web+app) with code https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5695378309513216
- Show a **prompt to install your app**

  - Article with code samples: https://web.dev/customize-install/
  - Documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native