# Smart banner for UWP

Tags: html, windows, web, uwp, meta

I made meta tags for android and IOS and both work but is there any meta tag for UWP applications?

```
<meta name="google-play-app" content="...">
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="...">
```

is there any meta tag for uwp?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any meta tag for UWP applications?

Currently no such tag supported for UWP app, this requires the native support from web browser, like [safari did](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

As the solution for [android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580770/5254458), you may use some libraries to pop up such banner.