# Directing user of website to a mobile app

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have a website (setup using Wordpress) and a mobile app, that is available for both Apple and Google.  Although my web theme is responsive I would like to give visitors the option of loading the app instead.  Is there any code I can put in the Wordpress theme/site that will check what sort of device the visitor is using and then present an option to redirect them to the app store (i guess this would be a popup).

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of things, once you know what this is called there's a wealth of material out there. On iOS there is a thing called Smart App Banners - see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

which is basically a meta tag that the browser on iPhone recognises and displays an app link. As this is used by many websites that have apps, it's likely users will be familiar with the concept when they see yours.

There is/was a WordPress plugin which adds the meta tag in: http://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-app-banners/ (now seemingly abandoned)

It looks like that plugin does something for Android too. Otherwise check out  [Creating an android smart app banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner)

It's worth checking the settings because it would be quite annoying to keep hitting an app banner on every page load. Ideally you'd only show it once.

Comment: bumping this to say i'd be wary of that plugin, its not well rated, not downloaded often, and hasn't been updated in 2 years. Aside from that, I tried out jquery.smartbanner today and it seems to not be working on android for me.