# Getting url from Smart App Banner in android

Tags: android, android-banner

When try to click the smart app banner in browser page while the application is launched and then how can i get the url from meta tag.please any reference or guide me in correct way.

Comment: Do not have any complete reference regarding  getting url from meta tag smart app banner in android.thats why have posted the question.if u need more information just comment  it regarding clearance.please don not make as '-1'

Comment: http://applinks.org/documentation/ take a look here

Comment: @AmrutBidri.Thanks.i will go through the docs.