# How can i make my website for mobiles to suggest downloading apk?

Tags: magento, mobile, web, responsive-design

I  have an apk and my website.

I want on mobiles to show a page just like this :http://www.livescore.com/ to suggest downloading or go to mobile view.

Help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an android smart app banner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner)

Comment: Not works for magento